# How can I adjust the fixed-width of a Neotree buffer?

Tags: window, osx

Using emacs 24, when I try to use the [Neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) package I am having issues with modifying the fixed-width of the window. I believe I have found the responsible chunk of lisp, but changing the value doesn't seem to help on reload.

```
(defcustom neo-window-width 25
  "*Specifies the width of the NeoTree window."
  :type 'integer
  :group 'neotree)
```

Comment: One of the very first things that I did when I tried out this library was to modify `neo-global--get-window` to replace `(neo-global--create-window)` with my own display-buffer-left function that sets the window width correctly.  In my opinion, `neo-global--create-window` just asks for trouble.  Essentially, you can create your own `display-buffer-left-function` that and the BUFFER and ALIST look like this:  `(lawlist-display-buffer-left (neo-global--get-buffer t) '((window-width . 33)))`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21544307/2112489

Comment: If you don't care about having a dynamic width. Just set the value like `(setq neo-window-width 40)` then kill current neotree buffer and run `neotree` again to see the update.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable `neo-window-fixed-size` and restart Neotree.

[image]

Comment: This does seem to couple the width to a buffer. If I change buffers it resizes to its original size.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using spacemacs and adding:

```
(setq neo-window-width 55)
```

to my `.spacemacs` file.

This is having no affect. Also, if I go into `customize-group` and select `neotree` and change the `Neo Window Width` the setting doesn't stick. Every time I restart Spacemacs the width defaults back to 32 and setting revert back to 32. I am saving for future sessions. Also, in the neotree `customize-group` under `Neo Window Width` it says, "CHANGED outside Customize."

I cannot find where this setting is being set. Any ideas?

I'm on 0.200.13@26.2 (spacemacs) running on macOS 10.14.6 installed through Homebrew.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer, but rather like a question!

Comment: Indeed. I didn't want to start another post on the same issue. Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: on doom emacs, this command works for me